# Jquery Swap checked disabled attr on change

Tags: jquery, checkbox, attr

Suppose to `check` `disable` selected checkbox and reverse the `check` `disable` on the other box. Seems to work till I try it again on the previously changed checkbox. Brain is fried for today. Would be very grateful for any insight or better code.

http://jsfiddle.net/sz7R4/

```
$('.changeCheck').change(function(event) { 
   var oldTarget = $(':checked').attr('id');
    console.log(oldTarget);
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').attr('checked', 'checked');
    $('#'+oldTarget).removeAttr('checked', 'checked').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you only target second input, you also need to target `change` event on first input. As well as you should use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr()`:

```
$('.changeCheck, #check1').change(function(event) { 
    $(this).prop("disabled", true).siblings().prop("disabled", false).prop('checked', false);
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sz7R4/2/)**

Comment: I was able to use your example and expand on it. I decided its better to have `.changeCheck` on all checkboxs so siblings works better. Thanks to all for help!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.changeCheck').change(function (event) {
    $('.changeCheck').prop({
        'checked': false,
        'disabled': false
    });
    $(this).prop({
        'checked': true,
        'disabled': true
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sz7R4/1/)**

You don't want to use `.removeAttr()` or `.attr()`, but rather `.prop()`. And wouldn't a radio button be a better option here?

Answer (score 0):

`.attr()` only changes the default attribute, it does not change the "live" attribute (as of jQuery 1.6). You need to use the `.prop()` method instead.